# Matrix Norm and Euclidean Norm

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-norms

A vector, say for example $ a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$, can be regarded not only as a vector but also as a 2 x 1 matrix. If we interpret it as a vector we can compute the $\ell_p$ norm of $a$. If we interpret it as a matrix we can compute its matrix norm, i.e:

$$
||a|| = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{||ax||}{||x||}
$$

My question is: If we interpret $a$ as a matrix,  is the matrix norm equal to any of the vector norms? I suspect that it would equal the Euclidean norm, as using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality yields

$$
||a|| = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{||ax||}{||x||} \leq \frac{||a|| ||x||}{||x||} = ||a|| = \sqrt5
$$

but I am not sure if this is correct. Any help would me highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What kind of object is $x$ and what norm is $\|x\|$?

Comment: $x$ is a vector, an arbitrary one, and $||x||$ I assume refers to its Euclidean norm, but the definition does not specify it.

Comment: What do you mean by $ax$, then?

Comment: Matrix multiplication, define $x = (x_1, x_2)$, then $ax = x_1 + 2x_2$. We could also say that it is dot product.

Comment: There’s no matrix by which you can right-multiply $a$ to produce a scalar. You need something like $a^Tx$ there.